# При инициализации TextView равен пустоте

Tags: android, java

Не могу отследить, почему происходит ошибка на некоторых девайсах, bugreport приходят ко мне на сервер с ошибкой:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.x.x/ru.x.x.Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ru.x.x.FragmentGroup.onViewCreated(SourceFile:100)
```

Ошибка происходит на строчке `tv_group.setText(template.getGroup().getName());`.
Я так понимаю `tv_group == null`, на моём девайсе всё хорошо работает, на некоторых других вылетает на этой строке. Думаю, дело в xml файле - `tools:context=""`.

**FragmentGroup.java**

```
public class FragmentGroup extends Fragment implements
    TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

public static FragmentGroup newInstance(Template tmplate, int position,
        FragmentLocation fragLoc) {
    tempPosition = position;
    template = tmplate;
    mFragLoc = fragLoc;
    return new FragmentGroup();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_group_fulltime,
                container, false);
    return mainView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) mainView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    TextView tv_group = (TextView) mainView
            .findViewById(R.id.group_name);
    tv_group.setText(template.getGroup().getName()); //На этой строке вылетает ошибка
    ImageView img_refresh = (ImageView) mainView
            .findViewById(R.id.refresh);
    if (tempPosition != -1)
        img_refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                isRefresh = true;
                new RefreshInfoDay().execute();
            }
        });
    else
        img_refresh.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    mTask.execute();
}
```

**layout/fragment_group_fulltime.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="ru.x.x.Activity$FragmentGroup" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#0069c2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:src="@drawable/group_header" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight=".99" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/group_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_main_left"
            android:text="Группа"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/group_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:src="@drawable/refresh_header" />
</LinearLayout>

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:context="ru.x.x.Activity$FragmentGroup" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @fortuna58rus, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ничего удивительного. Вы не учитываете жизненный цикл `Activity` и её фрагментов. Как следствие — неверная инициализация самого фрагмента. Посмотрите документацию и сэмплы из SDK. (Hint: `Fragment.setArguments()`/`Fragment.getArguments()`).

**Обновление**

Либо `putSerializable()`, в зависимости от того, какой интерфейс (`Serializable`, `Parcelable`) вы реализуете у `FragmentLocation`.

Comment: @falstaf Вы предлагаете в newInstance использовать setArguments? А как передать во Fragment объект FragmentLocation нужно использовать метод putParcelable(key, value)?

Comment: @falstaf спасибо, вы правильно заметили, но пока нет возможности проверить у меня. Я не могу ваш комментарий преобразовать в ответ.